# RewriteRule Irrespective of Trailing Slash in .htaccess

Tags: rewrite

I want to redirect URLs irrespective of trailing slashes. The reason is because my site enforces trailing slashes by default;  if an internal link is missing the trailing slash then I have a redirect chain ( /test -> /test/ -> /go-here/).

I've tried:

- This does not work: `RewriteRule ^test(/$|$) /go-here/ [R=301,L]`
- This works: `Redirect 301 /test /go-here/` (but I don't want to do this)

Essentially, I want a good way to redirect URLs for an instance like that below without having to have tons of lines in my .htacess file.

- `/test -> /go-here/`
- `/test/ -> /go-here/`

Answer (score 0):

Using the "once of nonce" operator which is short for {0,1}

```
RewriteRule ^test/?$ /go-here/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can use the ? operator to match it with a slash and without, this is the most precise way.

Another way worth mentioning though is to just match on the start of the string.  ^ matches the start and $ matches the end of a string in a regular expression. Usually people include both of those, but you don't have to include them both or even either of them (if you want to match on a string in the middle that isn't near the start or end).

So, this will also accomplish what you are after:

RewriteRule ^test /go-here/ [L,R=301]

Anything starting with "test" will get matched, regardless of slash or anything else that comes afterwards.

Be careful though as this will also match /testing or /tester.